# ERROR unwrapping an Optional value AND dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(:cell identifier)

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift

> this is app for search
>
> Not error before app running !

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SpotListCell")!

    if(cell.isEqual(NSNull))
    {
        cell = (NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("SpotListCell", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? UITableViewCell)!;
    }


    if tableView == self.tableView {
        cell.textLabel?.text = posts.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("title") as! NSString as String
    } else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.filteredPosts[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell
}
```

> Moment to run apps, searching the error.
>   The following error.

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

(lldb)

> Where should be modified?
>   Thank you for reading it.
>   Note I am a Korean high school student.

Comment: `AppDelegate.swift 

import UIKit @UIApplicationMain class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate { //this line error 


message and message : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is what is causing your troubles I guess:

`cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SpotListCell")!`

It seems your table view is unable to create a `SpotListCell` for you and since you add the `!` you force the compiler to give you the value regardless of it being `nil` or not.

In the next line you then say:

`if(cell.isEqual(NSNull))`

but cell is `nil` so you can not ask it for anything (and besides...`NSNull` probably isn't what you're looking for).

**Edit: updated my answer**

First you should register you Nib so the `UITableView` can use it.

- make an outlet to your `UITableView` and connect that:

  `@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!`
- Then in your `viewDidLoad()` you can do something like:
  `contentTableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "SpotListCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "SpotListCell")`

And finally you can use your cell like this, notice the `guard let`to safely unwrap your cell:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SpotListCell") else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    //Populate as you did before
    if tableView == self.tableView {
        cell.textLabel?.text = posts.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("title") as! NSString as String
    } else {
       cell.textLabel?.text = self.filteredPosts[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell    
}
```

See if that is any better (and I haven't checked it with a compiler so there might be errors...I'm sure the compiler will let you know :))

Hope that helps you.

Comment: tThis error is produced in other parts do you solve the problem.

Comment: AppDelegate.swift

import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate { //this line error message 

and message : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle

Comment: That is probably this line that is causing you trouble `cell = (NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("SpotListCell", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? UITableViewCell)!`

Comment: That's right. I Don't know how should I understand.

Comment: Basically it complains that it can not load the Xib file that you have created for your `SpotListCell`. So..first things first. Do you have a Xib file called SpotListCell in your project?

Comment: I'm sorry... What should I do with it? There's no some work when it comes to xib

Comment: Thank you so much. Now not an error is made if the search.
but No results, even when the search.